# I have bbpress-bundled-with-wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, bbpress

If I write :

`<iframe src=http://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbarackobama%2Fposts%2F10154508876046749&width=500 width="500" height="527" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

Then facebook post is embedded but it is followed by a weird box.

Sample:

[image]

Did I type in something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the werid facebook iframe box below your embeded facebook page?

Comment: Yes, that one! Why is appearing?

Comment: Did you embed iframe in the blog post page? Do you have a link to the sample page?

Comment: It was posted on bbpress-bundled-in-wordpress, not as a blog post to wordpress.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhQg2.png

Comment: Can this make any difference? <iframe src=http://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbarackobama%2Fposts%2F10154508876046749&width=500 width="500" height="527" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" />

Comment: I'm confused. What's the difference?